# Showing that we can always decompose $Y = \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] + \epsilon$.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, fake-proofs

The question is that

Let $Y$ be a random variable with finite mean and $X$ a random vector. $Y$ can always be decomposed as follows:

$Y = \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] +\epsilon$,

where $\epsilon$ is a scalar random variable that is uncorrelated with any function of $X$. True or False?

Since there is no limitation on what sort of function it should be I just defined the function $f:H_1 \rightarrow H_2$, where $H_1$ is the space of all real random vectors with dimension $\dim X$ and $H_2$ is the space of all real random variables, and let $f$ map any $A\in H_1$ to $Y - \mathbb{E}\left[Y|A\right]$. Then $\epsilon$ should correlate with $f(X)$. I don't see why this example doesn't work because I'm pretty sure the answer should be True.

The proof that it should be true looks something like:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon f(X)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon f(X)\;|X\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[f(X)\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon\;|X\right]\right] = 0$, since

$\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon\;|X\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\;|X\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y\;|X\right]\;|X\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\;|X\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[Y\;|X\right] = 0$, and

$\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon\right] = 0$, so that $\mathrm{Cov}\left(\epsilon, f(X)\right) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify some of the steps since the phrase "by definition of conditional expectation" is not quite accurate; instead, one is using linearity, measurability, and the tower property. :)

First, for any $\sigma(X)$-measurable $U$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf E}[\epsilon U] 
&=&
{\bf E}[(Y-{\bf E}[Y|X])U] 
\qquad\text{(by definition of }\epsilon \text{)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[UY]-{\bf E}[{\bf E}[Y|X]U] 
\qquad\text{(by linearity of expectation)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[UY]- {\bf E}[{\bf E}[UY|X]] 
\qquad \text{(}U \text{ is }\sigma(X)\text{-measurable, and property of conditional expectations)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[UY]- {\bf E}[UY] 
\qquad \text{(by tower property of conditional expectations)}\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
And, second,
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf E}[\epsilon] 
&=&
{\bf E}[Y-{\bf E}[Y|X]] 
\qquad\text{(by definition of }\epsilon \text{)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[Y]-{\bf E}[{\bf E}[Y|X]] 
\qquad\text{(by linearity of expectation)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[Y]- {\bf E}[Y] 
\qquad \text{(by tower property of conditional expectation)}\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf Cov}[\epsilon,U]
&=&
{\bf E}[(\epsilon -{\bf E}[\epsilon])(U-{\bf E}[U])]
\qquad\text{ (by definition of covariance)}\\
&=&
{\bf E}[\epsilon U]-{\bf E}[\epsilon]{\bf E}[U]
\qquad\text{ (using linearity of expectation)}\\
&=&
0 - 0\times {\bf E}[U] 
\qquad\text{ (using above results)}\\
&=&
0
\end{eqnarray*}
Using $\sigma(X)$-measurable $U$ in the above includes the case of $\mathbb{R}$-valued measurable functions $g$ of $X$ where one uses the usual interpretation of $g(X)$ as the random variable with value $g(X(\omega))$ at a particular $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean if we move away from functions with the image being a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ the proof fails to work? (For example if the function maps to a subset of the function space of random variables?)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your definition of $f:H_1\to H_2$ as $f(X)=Y-E[Y|X]$. $Y$ and $E[Y|X]$ are real random variables and hence so is $f(X)=Y-E[Y|X]$. And you are stating that $H_2$ is the space of real random variables. So, it looks good to me. To get a value one needs to evaluate at a particular $\omega\in\Omega$: $f(X)(\omega)=Y(\omega)- E[Y|X](\omega)$. Note that with your definition of $f$ you cannot write $f(X(\omega))$ though, which is how people usually interpret $f(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up my question! I think what you're saying is that the issue is that my defined $f$ means that the question of whether $f(X)$ is correlated with $\epsilon$ didn't even make sense in the end, as we're then finding the covariance of two objects of different types.

Comment: No, I think you are ok: $\epsilon$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable and so is $f(X)=Y-E[Y|X]$. So, $Cov[\epsilon,f(X)]$ makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $\varepsilon=Y-\mathbb E[Y|X]$, and compute for any $X$-measurable random variable $U$ the quantity
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\varepsilon U] &= \mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y|X]) U]\\
&=\mathbb E[YU]-\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|X] U]\\
&=\mathbb E[YU]-\mathbb E[YU]\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
by definition of conditional expectation.

Your example is not well defined, "$f$ maps any $A$ to $Y-\mathbb E[Y|A]$", the second term is still random, it is not a value.

Comment: Thanks I get that part but I'm wondering why my fake counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: As I said, $f$ is not a function in your example.

Comment: I'm confused why it's not a function because I thought a function can map from any space to any space, so why can't I map to the function space of random variables?

Comment: Your mapping $f$ is from $H_1$ to the space of function from $\Omega\to H_2$, this is what I mean by "$f$ is not a function" (in the end it is but not on the spaces you belived)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No, I disagree. His $f$ maps from $H_1$ to $H_2$ where $H_2$ is the set of measurable maps from $\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, not to the space of functions $\Omega\to H_2$.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.

Comment: As long as we all understand and agree!